# Team foundation. building a solution with multi tier projects, DLL and Telerik controls

Tags: asp.net, dll, tfs, telerik, multi-tier

I have a website (WSPs) developed with ASP.net, and 3 projects (BLL/DAL/DTO). 
I also use Telerik controls.

My build is failing in TFS, and I suspect it is because I am not referencing the projects and the Telerik dlls properly.

When I added the projects and website in Source control explorer, the dlls were not included.

I had to add them later on, in the bin folder of the website, but I don't think they are picked up. Also I just realised that they are not in the projects. Can anyone please explain to me how to do it.

Also when I check out my project and start working on it, if I modify any class in one of the project I cannot build my project locally. The changes cannot be added.

Attached are :
- a source control showing the structure of my application in TFS
- the Workspace
- The DLL that should be in the bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

Store any 3rd party assemblies in a shared folder.

Add the reference to projects using the shared folder. For the website itself, add a refresh file to /bin so that it copies the latest version in from the shared folder when built.

Comment: Should I create a library folder from the Main Folder, and add the  telerik and Ajax dlls in there. How does the project knows it is there. How do I reference it?

Comment: Should I put the project dlls in there as well? I am not sure how it works. For instance in the BLL project. I should have a reference to the DAL and the DTO project. Where do they go

Comment: Create a folder in the root of the solution folder and place the assemblies in here. When adding a reference (non-project), simply browse to that folder from the dialog. Project references are just that, so no need to do anything differently, just add the reference to the project.

Comment: I am sorry to be a bit slow, but what you are saying is I should move my Telerik and ajaxcontrol dlls from the bin folder in my solution to a folder called for instance Library in the root of my solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to check any DLL's into source control. You should add Nuget packages for all of you external references. When you reference your own second party output or third party DLL without Nuget packages you should create Nuget packages as required and host then yourself...